# I need to know what pygame version to get on my windows 10 laptop for python 2.7.13

Tags: python, windows, pygame, versions

I've tried lots of different versions and when I try to import pygame and access things from it, I just get an error saying basically that it can't import pygame. What pygame version should I get? And what's a good way to test it to see if it works?

Comment: Did you make sure to get rid of your old versions of pygames when installing if you had any, and did you make sure to install pygames for the correct version of python?

Comment: Yes. I got the correct version and removed the old pygames.

Answer (score 0):

Let pip find the right version for the python it is run with.

```
py -2.7 -m pip install pygame  # or
py -2.7 -m pip install -U pygame  # if some 2.7 compatible version
py -2.7 -m pip uninstall pygame  # if necessary, because above gives errors
```

Comment: I'll be sure to try this soon and get back to you to as to if it worked.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working for me. It says there's an error and red highlights `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [pygame.org/download](http://pygame.org/download.shtml), there they have a bunch of options for windows 32 bit in the windows section. Just at the bottom of the Windows section, you see a link to download some pre release binaries for 64 bit windows, the direct link is [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Once on the page you will scroll down to a hundreds of links to some or other applications, but as they are alphabetically arranged, you must have no trouble in finding "Pygame" section. Once at the pygame section, i think the second link is what you want.

If you don't understand or get stuck in any of the process above, you can watch the video i learnt pygame from: [YouTube/thenewboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5F-aGDIYaM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq).

Comment: Okay, how do I tell if I should get 32 bit or 64 bit? It seems like I need a complete tutorial for my specific computer because nothing I've tried works. I also think it might be easier to get python 3.4 but the online course I'm taking uses 2.7.

Comment: Go to My Computer/This PC icon, right click in the white-space and click on 'Properties'. In the specifications down there it will show 'System-Type'. Yours probably i can already guess it's 64-bit. But still, if you want to be sure yourself, follow the steps.

Comment: Yeah, it's 64-bit, and I had tried doing the 64-bit and it still wasn't working. (I would think that 32-bit would still work on a 64-bit computer.) But I contacted Python to see if they can help me so we'll see.

Comment: Why don't you just download Python 3.6 or 3.4, it takes only a while after all... and i'm pretty sure there was a bug somewhere in 2.7 because, i tried it on Mac and i was surprised that the same code that ran smoothly on my PC, didn't run on Mac so... if you can, save the trouble and GO 3.X!

Comment: Ofcourse, now we really are shifting from the topic but, the only difference at basic level coding between Python 2.x and 3.x is with the print and input functions. So there is no problem with the code of 2.x not running in 3.x.

Comment: Okay, because I'm learning from a course and he's using 2.7. So if I can get Pygame to work with 3.X, then it should be all good.